# Template django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una página web con Python y Django, tengo una tabla `ofertas_educativas` y otra tabla sede la cual tiene una relación de muchos a muchos con oferta educativa, al hacer la consulta en la base de datos.

```
ofertas = models.ManyToManyField(oferta_educativa, blank = True)
```

Al consultar los datos en el template:

```
    {% for p in ofertas%}
       <tr>
            <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
            <td>{{p.sede.nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{p.jornada}}</td>
            <td>{{p.nivel}}</td>
            <td>{{p.grado}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

No muestra el nombre de la sede a la cual esta asignada esa oferta educativa. ¿Como lo hago para poder mostrar el nombre de esa sede?

Comment: Deberias mostrar el codigo que tienes en el template, de la vista y del modelo para que podamos ayudarte de mejor forma

Answer (score 0):

Tienes algún método string en el modelo sede?. Prueba a añadir un método string al modelo sede:

```
class Sede(models.Model):
    nombre_sede = models.CharField(maxlength=100)
    ...
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_sede
```